# Type inference failure using lamdba but not while using closure in kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa, option-type

I have the following dtos in kotlin

```
UserInfo
UserInfoEntity
```

an interface

```
interface Transformer<S: Data, T: DataEntity> {
    fun transform(s: S): T
    fun transform(t: T): S
}
```

Implementation of the interface

```
class UserInfoTransformer() :Transformer<UserInfo, UserInfoEntity>
/* both methods implemented */ 
override fun transform(userInfo: UserInfo): UserInfoEntity
override fun transform(userInfoEntity: UserInfoEntity): UserInfo
```

A repository

```
interface UserInfoRepo: JpaRepository<UserInfoEntity, Long>
/*save, Jpa provides me the save method of signature 
<S extends T> S save(S entity) 
UserInfoEntity interpreted for S
*/
```

Now, the following code works

```
fun saveUser(userInfo: UserInfo): UserInfo =
        Optional.of(userInfo)
            .map(userInfoTransformer::transform)
            .map {
                userInfoRepo.save(it)
            }
            .map(userInfoTransformer::transform).get()
```

**But the following code does not work**

```
fun saveUser(userInfo: UserInfo): UserInfo =
    Optional.of(userInfo)
        .map(userInfoTransformer::transform)
        .map(userInfoRepo::save)
        .map(userInfoTransformer::transform).get()
```

I get the following errors:

```
Error:(29, 14) Kotlin: Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter U in fun <U : Any!> map(p0: Function<in UserInfoEntity!, out U!>!): Optional<U!>!
Please specify it explicitly.
Error:(29, 32) Kotlin: Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter S in fun <S : UserInfoEntity!> save(p0: S!): S!
Please specify it explicitly.
Error:(30, 39) Kotlin: Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public abstract fun transform(s: UserInfo): UserInfoEntity defined in com.myswiftly.core.xformer.Transformer
public abstract fun transform(t: UserInfoEntity): UserInfo defined in com.myswiftly.core.xformer.Transformer
```

Why map {  } is different from map(). 
Surprisingly, intellij is unable detect these during compilation. I get these while, attempting to start the application.

Comment: You could make this a lot simpler by removing Optional entirely. `UserInfo` can't be null because of the way it is declared.

Comment: Even if I use 'UserInfo?' and modify all the respective methods, the same issue.

Comment: My point is, `Optional` doesn't give you any benefit here. Because `UserInfo` can never be null, there really is no point in wrapping your operations in `Optional`. Just operate directly on `UserInfo` without `Optional`.

Comment: I also I tried userInfo
            .run(userInfoTransformer::transform)
            .run(userInfoRepo::save)
            .run(userInfoTransformer::transform) and didn't work

Comment: What about `userInfoRepo.save(userInfoTransformer.transform(userInfo))`

Comment: Again, that would work but it's not the task here. I don't want to nest the arguments but chain the methods. This would work just fine in Java. Also when I use the closure instead of lambda expression, it works in kotlin as well.

Comment: @Todd I just updated the title for better uunderstanding

Comment: Is that right that you have the new type inference enabled in IDEA in "File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Kotlin Compiler", and there is no error highlighting in the editor. But when you disable the option, errors start to appear?

Comment: Yes that's true